# Best way to sort 2d Array Php

Tags: php, sorting

I'm reading from a text file that has 2 columns. name,rank So it looks like this:

```
quxerm,6
brock,5
chris,15
```

So the 2d array looks like [0][0] = quxerm and [0][1]=6 [1][0] = brock [1][1]=5

I already have them into a 2d array like I showed above.

I need to sort these values in descending order by the integer column. How can I sort this?

Comment: What do you want to sort? The string or integer column?

Comment: I want to sort by the integer column.

Answer (score 1):

@CBergau's answer is almost perfect but the order will be ascending instead of descending.
To get it descending just switch the return values of the compare function which is called by usort. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php for more information.

```
function cmp(array $a, array $b) {
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($arr, 'cmp');
```

Example: http://codepad.org/QRTQLxTh

You could also extend the compare function for example to order ascending by name when the rank is the same by using strcmp. See http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strcmp.php for more information.

```
function cmp(array $a, array $b) {
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    }
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Example: http://codepad.org/SeRTE3Ym

**Note**: I've not enough reputation yet to just comment on @CBergau's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead, and then you can use all the functions relatives to maps like [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

Answer (score 0):

take the array as arr[i][j].

try comparing only by changing the values of i.

`for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
for(int k=1;k<3;k++)
if(arr[i][1]>arr[k][1])
max=i`

and you can retrieve max by :-
`arr[max][0]//name of max
arr[max][1]//value of max`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sorted = array();
foreach($yourArray as $a){
 $sorted[$a[1]] = $a[0];
}
ksort($sorted);
vardump($sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should sort by the integer column:

```
usort(
    $data,
    function ($arrayOne, $arrayTwo) {
        return ($arrayOne[1] < $arrayTwo[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If there are no duplicate names, you can simply assign the rank for the key (name), and sort that array while preserving keys.

```
$data["quxerm"] = 6;
$data["brock"] = 5;
$data["chris"] = 15;
asort($data, SORT_NUMERIC);
```